# Slice queryset after order_by() in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have `order_by()` model django and got queryset following result:

```
queryset = <QuerySet [<MyModel: MyModel object (4)>, <MyModel: MyModel object (2)>, 
<MyModel: MyModel object (1)>, <MyModel: MyModel object (3)>, <MyModel: MyModel object (5)>]>
```

The result is not sorted by id.

And I want slice queryset that have order `MyModel` with `id greater than 1` to get the following results:

```
new_queryset = <QuerySet [<MyModel: MyModel object (4)>, <MyModel: MyModel object (2)>]>
```

Is there any way to slice without loop like this to reduce the query ?

```
for index in range(len(queryset)):
    if queryset[index].id == 1:
        new_queryset = queryset[:index]
        break
```

Comment: What is the default ordering in your queryset?

Comment: I have 2 fields about datetime for order_by like this: 

.order_by(F("publish_datetime").desc(nulls_last=True), "-modified")

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `filter` or `exclude` functions that the `QuerySetManager` provides. Basically you can do the following:

```
new_queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(id__gt=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are ordering the queryset based on `publish_datetime` and `modified`, you can simply get the record with needed id, and filter the queryset according to the ordering relevant to the object, like this:

```
from django.db.models import F, Q

reference_object = MyModel.objects.get(id=1)
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(
    Q(publish_datetime__lt=reference_object.publish_datetime) |
    Q(
        Q(publish_datetime=reference_object.publish_datetime) &
        Q(modified__gt=reference_object.modified)
    )
)
```

You will get the results where posts were published before the needed object, or with the same published time, but with more recent modified date

Answer (score 0):

You can slice the list result as shown below:

```
new_queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(id__gt=1)[:5]
```

The 5 means the only 5 records would be displayed according to your filtered queryset.